# Did the galactic Republic keep up the manufacturing of Clones?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In *Star Wars: Episode II – Attack of the Clones* Obi-Wan discovers the Clone Army that has been created on Kamino, this army is then used by the Jedi to fight the Trade Federation.

After the events of *Attack of the Clones* did the Galactic Republic continue to make clone soldiers or did they simply use the ones already created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *The Clone Wars* TV series it is mentioned that a bill is passed for the creation of 5 million more clone troopers.

> **Narrator:** War on many fronts! While battles are fought by Clones in the field, a different war is waged in the Galactic Senate. As heavy losses add up, a group of senators led by Halle Burtoni of Kamino propose an escalation of troop production. Senator Padmé Amidala, recognizing that more troops will only prolong the fighting, works tirelessly with her allies to introduce a bill to cut down military spending and stop the creation of more Clone Troopers...
>
> <sub>*The Clone Wars*, Season 2 Episode 15, "Senate Murders"</sub>

It is later reiterated about the creation of more Clone Troopers trying to be ordered with Padme again trying to fight back on it.

> **Halle Burtoni:** Chancellor Palpatine, in light of this unprovoked attack on Coruscant and the vulnerabilities it raises, I propose the Republic purchase an additional 5 million clone troopers.

> **Padmé Amidala:** Can't you all see this bill is shortsighted l? Millions of clones won't win this war. The only winner will be the Banking Clan. They want to pass this bill so badly, they're using scare tactics to sway votes.
>
> <sub>*The Clone Wars*, Season 3 Episode 11, "Pursuit of Peace"</sub>

Comment: Plus, we see child Clone troops and trainees in S02E20 ("Death Trap") and S03E01 ("Clone Cadets").

Comment: Off topic, but I still think that the biggest issue with Halle Burtoni's plan is that it takes **10 years** for new Clones to grow up and be ready to fight.  Is he honestly saying that he expects the war to still be going on in a decade?

Comment: Burtoni is from Kamino, and so what if the war ends before the clones grow up? It's not uncommon in government procurement contracts that if the government cancels the order after a certain period of time, at least some of the agreed-upon payment is made to the contractor. If payment is in advance, even better.

Comment: There's a conversation in _Force Awakens_ between Kylo Ren and Capt. Phasma about the use (or non-use) of clones in their army, so they're still at least an option well after the events of Episode II.